# Orphaned "close this dialog" dialog when viewing an election as a moderator on mobile

Tags: bug, design, election, responsive-design, waffle-bar

When viewing an election on a site where you are a moderator while on mobile, a "close this dialog" dialog appears at the bottom of the page. It looks like the same thing that appears at the top of the waffle bar for flags.
It scrolls with the page and disappears when you click on it; I'm not sure if it's attached to something I can't see or if it's just orphaned.

This happens regardless of if you voted in that particular election or not. It also shows up for elections that haven't started yet.

[image: Screenshot of "close this dialog" on an election page]

This does not happen on the full, non-mobile site, nor on a site where I'm not a moderator.